# Why use cloneNode when I can clone a node using querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cloning

Below two function does same thing - first they copy an element then clear the body and then add the element back. My question is which one is better and in what conditions cloneNode using function or the other one will not work ?

**Using querySelector**

```
function noahArc(animal) {
  // Preserve the poor animal and its children
  var arc = document.querySelector(animal);

  // Flood the entire body with rage, water and thunder
  document.body.innerHTML = "";

  // Restore the preserved animal into the post-apocalyptic world
  document.body.appendChild(arc);
}

noahArc('.asd');
```

**Using cloneNode**

```
function noahArc(animal) {
  // Preserve the poor animal and its children
  var arc = document.getElementsByClassName(animal)[0].cloneNode(true);

  // Flood the entire body with rage, water and thunder
  document.body.innerHTML = "";

  // Restore the preserved animal into the post-apocalyptic world
  document.body.appendChild(arc);
}

noahArc('asd');
```

Comment: You are using `querySelector` in both solutions?

Comment: I have no idea why you'd use `.cloneNode()` in *any* situation where you don't actually want a second copy of the node. `querySelector` and `getElementsByClassName` don't seem relevant to what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Please don't edit your question when you already have an answer. Now it looks like T.J. Crowder doesn't know what he's talking about, and I ensure you, he does :).

Comment: Arshad - What's the point of the `querySelector` / `getElementsByClassName` edit? Either way, you get a reference to the element in the document, then destroy the element. The way you're using them, you just end up doing the same thing.

Comment: Apologies for editing.

Comment: @t.j.Crowder I know it wont make any difference. I did it just because of bergi's comment.

Comment: @squint my point is that if you can use arc variable later after removing body nodes, isnt it like having a copy for later use ?

Comment: @t.j.crowder In the edit that I did, it wont make any difference on using getElementsByClassName. But if I had used getElementsByClassName in place of querySelector in the first example, it will not be possible to add back the node because the node returned by getElementsByClassName are live whereas in case of querySelector they aren't.

Comment: @ArshadKhan: Not a copy. It's just a reference to the element, identical to that which you're getting with `.getElementsByTagName`. So it's not doing the same thing as `.cloneNode(true)`.

Comment: @squint `getElementsByTagName` will not work in first case where I have used `querySelector` because latter return element of static node whereas form returns a `htmlCollection`

Comment: I meant to type `...ByClassName`, but either way it doesn't matter that it returns an HTMLCollection, because you're retrieving the `[0]` element from the collection. It's two different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @squint maybe I am not getting what you are trying to say. Could you elaboarate a bit?

Comment: @ArshadKhan: Your statements above about `getElementsByClassName` are wrong. Yes, the NodeList from `getElementsByClassName` is live, but that doesn't matter; by the time you've wiped out the contents of body, you've *already* retrieved the element from the NodeList and released your reference to the NodeList. It makes no difference whatsoever which you use, in that code.

Comment: You can't clone a node using `querySelector`. It only selects, doesn't clone.

Comment: Your question states that assigning the result of `querySelector(...)` is the same as `getElementsByClassName(...)[0].cloneNode(true)`. That's not the case. If you drop the `.cloneNode(true)`, then they are exactly the same in that they're both giving you the first element found with the `asd` class. In other words, they both are simply doing a DOM selection, and neither one is making a copy of the element itself. When you add `.cloneNode(true)`, then you *are* making a copy of the node, but that's true no matter what you used to select the node.

Comment: @squint: **Very** well put.

Comment: Proof that you get the same behavior with `getElementsByClassName` in the first example (on a browser where that example works at all -- so, not IE): http://jsbin.com/cugobupinu/edit?html,output

Comment: @squint you are right. Its my fault , actually I did a mistake by editing the question. I was doin something like getElementsByClassName(...).cloneNode(true) and while appending element i was doing something like document.body.appendChild(arc[0]);.. great thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for the avoidance of doubt: `querySelector` does not clone elements. It just gives you a reference to the element that already exists. In a non-buggy browser, that reference remains valid even if you wipe the conents of body after you get the reference. It just means the element isn't in the document anymore.

Second, your edit and various comments suggesting there's a difference in your code depending on whether you use `querySelector` or `getElementsByClassName` to select the element are incorrect. In the code shown, it makes no difference whatsoever. The only difference of consequence in your examples is whether you clone the node.

So, looking at the two examples:

Your first example will fail in <s>some versions of</s> IE because of a bug it has where it wipes the contents of the descendant element when you assign to the `innerHTML` of its ancestor even when you have a reference to the descendant element. It *shouldn't* fail, but it will. (This bug cost me **hours** of debugging time sometime last year...) I don't think Edge has this bug. I've just verified it's still an issue with IE11 using this test:

```js
function noahArc(animal) {
  var arc = document.querySelector(animal);
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  document.body.appendChild(arc);
}

noahArc('.asd');
console.log("Done, you should still see 'this is the div' above, but you won't in IE");
```

```html
<div class="asd">this is the div</div>
```

Other than that, neither is "better." It depends on what you want to do.

Your first example attempts to keep the **same** element in the document (which may have event handlers attached to it). It doesn't make a copy, and only works (on browsers where it works) because the original is removed from the document by assigning to its ancestor's `innerHTML`.

Your second example creates a *copy* of the element (which won't have event handlers on it).

Which you use depends on what you want to achieve, and what browsers you want to support.

Comment: To add to this, by cloning the node you are consuming more memory than with the first approach.

Comment: @MichaelCamden: In the OP's example, you're doing so very, very briefly.

Comment: Didn't know that about IE and `.innerHTML`. I assume using `.removeChild` doesn't have this bug?

Comment: @squint: Correct.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Added a fix in my legacy `.innerHTML` patch.

Comment: @t.j.crowder my point is that if you can use arc variable later after removing body nodes, isnt it like having a copy for later use ?

Comment: @ArshadKhan: No, it's not a copy. It's the original element. You've just removed it from the DOM (later, by wiping out the body of the document). That doesn't copy it.

Comment: @T.j.Crowder Ohhk, now I get it. Thank you so much for answering question.

Comment: @t.j.crowder object, nodelist, htmlcollection are indeed confusing.

Comment: What exactly is that bug in IE about? It does not destroy the element that is removed from the DOM via `innerHTML`, but it does empty it? Can you link to a bug report?

Comment: @Bergi: Setting `innerHTML` on an ancestor element in IE removes all of the children from all descendant nodes -- it cleans them out, their text nodes, descendant elements, etc. So although we still have a reference to one of those elements and it isn't removed from memory, it becomes empty. I don't have the bug report to hand.